# Why does my webview doesn't show the webrtc camera in ios?

Tags: ios, webview, permissions

I'm working with the Licode webrtc system. In the web browser works very well and now I want to use it on mobile devices with the help of a webview. I was researching and saw that the webview I want to use (crosswalk) [is not compatible with webrtc systems in ios](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Does-ionic-framework-support-WebRTC) but it is in Android as I could verify.

I Installed the [camera plugin](https://web.archive.org/web/20220523050143/https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera)

and also I installed plugins to give [camera permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-ios-camera-permissions)

But nevertheless I still can not get the webrtc system's camera to show up in my webview.

My question is:
Is there any way to operate the camera on the crosswalk webview in ios?

If it is not like this:
Do you know any way to use the Licode webrtc system with a webview?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't currently use `getUserMedia()` in a WebView on iOS, hence capturing camera from there won't work.

Comment: I have seen that to have webrtc, some people recommend using this [plugin](https://github.com/BasqueVoIPMafia/cordova-plugin-iosrtc)  .
I have seen that to have webrtc, some people recommend using this plugin. But I do not understand how to use it. As I understand, this plugin will help me to pass what I have from Licode to an appRTC but I'm not sure how to achieve this. Have you used it?.